# ButterworthFilterModel consumes the memory too much

Tags: filtering, memory, signal-processing

I have a simple filter which is a result of the these questions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46500/data-filtering-using-butterworth-filter) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46380/butterworthfilter-data-filter).

I have to use this filter in a `Do` loop but I found that this filter consume the memory too much even I am not storing any thing. It is just direct calculation.

For example:

```
filter[n_, ω_, b_, data_] := Reverse[
  RecurrenceFilter[
   ToDiscreteTimeModel[ButterworthFilterModel[{n, ω}], b],
   Reverse[
    RecurrenceFilter[
     ToDiscreteTimeModel[ButterworthFilterModel[{n, ω}], b], 
     data]]]]

datatest = RandomReal[{-30, 200}, {100, 100}];

Do[indicator = i; 
  filter[8, 0.039063, 3.2, #] & /@ datatest;, {i, 1, 100}];
```

When I run this code the memory was consumed too much.

[image]

Can anyone help me in this and tell me what is wrong so that I get such consumption in the memory?

Comment: The basic problem is that you are using an inappropriate filter. Butterworth filters are old-style analog filters that were efficient in the days when you needed to use op amps and transisters. There are many very efficient digital filters that can do a much better job, especially in 2D.

Comment: @bills I really appreciate your comment but I am unfortunately unfamiliar with filtering techniques. Can you suggest another solution. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If smoothing then try Meanfilter or GasssianFilter, or maybe BandpassFilter, or for highpass edge-detection try EdgeDetect or Highpass... all of these are much easier to use than Butterworth (they don't require ToDiscreteTimeModel or RecurrenceFilter) they just operate right on the 2D data,

Comment: @bills, yes you are right, there are other filters that do the same job. It appears that `ButterworthFilterModel` and `ToDiscreteTimeModel` use Internal DumpSave each time with different local variables and that is probably the reason for memory high usage. I have tried other filters as you suggested and they work fine with not problem on the memory. thanks